# How to go through all the windows of application even the minimized ones?

Tags: macos, keyboard

If I have three windows open in Safari and minimize one of them, then I try to switch between windows by pressing Control+'  it only switches to windows that re not minimized. How do I include that window that was minimized?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly satisfying your request, but Expose in 10.6 (not sure about Lion) shows minimised windows in a subsection at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any keyboard shortcut, but it's doable with mouse/trackpad with exposé in both Lion and Snow Leopard.

In Lion there is a 4 finger down gesture to get all current app windows.
In Snow Leopard, clicking and holding an icon in the dock for 2 seconds does this too, it can be bound to a screen edge (hot corner) or a mouse button.